# pipe simple split in java

Tags: java

am getting problem while using split with pipeline.but with other characters it works well.What am doing wrong please help me.

```
String s ="H|PONumber1|1|1";
String arr[] = s.split("|");
for(int i=0;i <arr.length;i++ )
  System.out.println("arr["+i+"] : "+arr[i]);
```

**Output :**

```
arr[0] : 
arr[1] : H
arr[2] : |
arr[3] : P
arr[4] : O
arr[5] : N
arr[6] : u
arr[7] : m
arr[8] : b
arr[9] : e
arr[10] : r
arr[11] : 1
arr[12] : |
arr[13] : 1
arr[14] : |
arr[15] : 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pipe is being treated as a regex special character. Just escape it via `\\|` and you'll be good. From the [javadoc on String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)...

> Splits this string around matches of the given **regular expression**.

If you want to be safe, always pass your text to `Pattern.quote(stringToSplitOn)`;

Comment: You can also use `s.split("[|]");`.

Comment: @Makoto you can but I would argue (rather weakly) that is cryptic. I updated my answer to include a general escaping strategy though.